# What am I missing in this Alert React Bootstrap example?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

It's been a day and my head is bloody from beating it on this wall: two easy react-bootstrap Alert examples that are invisible. I manually edited the style and removed the 'fade' style (for the alert titled 'check it out'), and the alert shows. But they are both supposed to show by default.

What did I do wrong? I am new to React. But I did not expect such an easy example to go wrong.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, FormGroup, FormControl, FormLabel } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Alert } from 'react-bootstrap';
import '../styles/login.css';

const Login: React.FC<{}> = () => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");  

...

    return (
        <div className="Login"> 
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <FormGroup controlId="email">
                    <FormLabel>Email</FormLabel>
                    <FormControl
                        autoFocus
                        type="string"
                        value={email}
                        onChange={(e: any) => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup controlId="password">
                    <FormLabel>Password</FormLabel>
                    <FormControl
                        value={password}
                        onChange={(e: any) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                        type="password" />
                </FormGroup>
                <Button block disabled={!validateForm()} type="submit">
                    Login
                </Button> 

                <Alert key={1} variant="success">check it out!</Alert> 

                <Alert show={true} variant="success">
                    <Alert.Heading>Oh snap! You got an error!</Alert.Heading>
                    <p>
                        Change this and that and try again. Duis mollis, est non commodo
                        luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit.
                        Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.
                    </p>
                </Alert>
            </form> 
        </div>
    );
}

export default Login;
```

[image: Removing 'fade' from the element style shows the element]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, well, the examples in the official documentation have fade true by default. This means they don't show. This isn't official, because the docs for react-bootstrap don't say this -- the docs for reactstrap do. [Reactstrap](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/alerts/) is a competing package to react-boostrap.

So it seems the transition is 'fade' by default. Which means that a newb will use the example and see nothing at all.

The react-bootstrap docs do mention the transition group, but don't say that they're defaulted to false. They also don't tell how to express a transition inline. I was trying: transition={{Fade: {in: false}}. If you need to see that through, look [here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/utilities/transitions/). I tried inline and through the  element, but no go.

If I switch to reactstrap, the example alert is shown with the below code:

```
 <Alert color='primary' fade={false}>check it out!</Alert>
```

Which seems to be a lot simpler than struggling with react-bootstrap beta. So I'll use reactstrap to alert.